# Como checar se vários input criado dinamicamente está vazia?

Tags: javascript, css, knockoutjs

Tenho esse Input que é gerando via Knockoutjs:

```
<input type="text" class="req" placeholder="" data-bind="value:Request" />
```

Porém tenho que verifica se está vazio e se estiver aplica uma css especifico:
Como pode ser criado vários campos igual, eu so conseguir aplicar no primeiro campo a minha validação.

Meu JavaScript:

```
if ($(".req").val() == "") { 
    $(".req").addClass(validationClassErrosType.input)
}
validationCheckImage($("#req"), $("#req").parent());
```

A imagem do input:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom ele sempre pega a classe do primeiro. como poderia fazer isso via javaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo básico com jQuery, veja se consegue adaptar ao seu caso.

```js
$('#testarInputs').click(function(){
  $('.teste').each(function(){
    if(this.value == ''){
      $(this).css('border','1px solid red');
    }else{
      $(this).css('border','');
    }
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="teste">
<input class="teste">
<input class="teste">
<input class="teste">
<input class="teste">
<input class="teste">
<input class="teste">
<input class="teste">
<input class="teste">

<input type="button" id="testarInputs" value="Testar">
```

Comment: Agora conseguir fazer funcionar. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Tente isto :

```
for(var x = 0; x < $('.req').length; x++){
 if($('.req')[x].val() === ""){
  console.info("Adicionar Css");    
 }
}
```

Comment: bom não é bem pegar o primeiro elemento eu quero pega todo so que ir colocando a classe no que está vazio.